# How to translate an ADB command line control ---> to MonkeyRunner Python script

Tags: android-activity, adb, monkeyrunner, calabash-android

When I run this on the command line it brings up the screen on my device to change the language.

```
$ adb shell am start -a android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS
```

works great.

I am trying the same functionality into a Python script that monkeyrunner calls.
How do you translate the above into something that will work with monkeyrunner / python?

e.g. I tried:

```
device = Monkeyrunner.waitForConnection()
package = 'android.settings'
activity = 'LOCALE_SETTINGS'
runComponent = package + '/' activity

device.startActivity(component=runComponent
```

This does nothing. No error message. But nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS` is not a `component` but an `action`. You can do either

```
device.startActivity(action='android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS')
```

or

```
device.startActivity(component='com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$LocalePickerActivity')
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks. In genereal how do I go about issuing commands via device.startActivity? I really can't find any documentation as to all the things I can do... and importantly ... how to do these things.

Comment: It's more productive to ask specific questions. The broader the question - the higher the chance it will go unanswered.